# How to define test for nested(?) const, JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm using javascript for the first time in a work setting, and have to test a code running within our questionnare solution. The answers can only be true or false, and the check is written like this:

```
if(Page.Group.Question.Answer){*do something*};
```

In my test-code I have to define Page.Group.Question.Answer myself and I can't seem to find out how to do it, although I am sure it is quite easy. I have tried the following so far:

```
var Page.Group.Question.Answer = true;
```

and

```
let Page.Group.Question.Answer = true;
```

And then I tried to define a const, but I couldn't find out how it should be nested.

What is the correct syntax?

Comment: have you tried `Page.Group.Question.Answer = true;` - oh, wait, you need to defined that whole thing?  `const Page = {Group:{Question:{Answer:true}}}` - though, that is unlikely to be at all useful

Comment: These are *three nested objects* you'd need to define like `{ Group: { ... } }`… If you don't have that structure already, are you sure you need it?!

Comment: I am not sure at all that I need it, but unfortunately this is just a small dip into a larger system and I can't redefine that much. Just have to work with what has been given. What you two suggests worked great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With some help from Jaromanda X and deceze the answer is that I need to define it as:

```
const Page = {Group: {Question: {Answer: true}}}
```